# Value of a variable matching the first row of another variable by group

Tags: r, dataframe

As in the title, I would like to have a process that allows me to assign a set of unique values of a first variable, to the most common value of a second variable, matching the first row of a third value. Example:

```
   Name      Year      Job
   Alicia    1990      Butcher
   Alicia    1991      Baker
   George    1989      Scientist
   George    1990      Banker
   George    1991      Banker
```

I would like to easily identify what is the first job each unique Name did:

```
   Name      Year      Job         First Job
   Alicia    1990      Butcher     Butcher
   Alicia    1991      Baker       Butcher
   George    1989      Scientist   Scientist
   George    1990      Banker      Scientist
   George    1991      Banker      Scientist
```

Comment: Your title was way too long, kinda unclear and was not matching what you had in the body of your question. Please consider a shorter, more general title if what I have up is not desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table` for this:

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)[order(Year),FirstJob:=Job[1],.(Name)][]
## or using which.min instead of ordering as akrun suggested:
# setDT(df1)[,FirstJob:=Job[which.min(Year)], .(Name)][]

 #>       Name Year       Job  FirstJob
 #>  1: Alicia 1990   Butcher   Butcher
 #>  2: Alicia 1991     Baker   Butcher
 #>  3: George 1989 Scientist Scientist
 #>  4: George 1990    Banker Scientist
 #>  5: George 1991    Banker Scientist
```

***Data:***

```
read.table(text="Name      Year      Job
                 Alicia    1990      Butcher
                 Alicia    1991      Baker
                 George    1989      Scientist
                 George    1990      Banker
                 George    1991      Banker",
           header=T, stringsAsFactors=F) -> df1
```

Comment: To add a second option you might use : `fread(..., key = c("Name", "Year"))` instead of `read.table` and then do `df1[, new := first(Job), by = Name]` .

Comment: @markus OP probably already have their data loaded, so using `fread` and skipping `setDT` would cause confusion. Not using `fread`, then I am not fan of using `first` or `...[1]` (subsetting) without ordering since that would presume that data is ordered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! What about if I want to use the mode instead of min ? (so "most common job" instead of "first job"(George = Banker))

Comment: @Homard You need to create a `mode` function: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_mean_median_mode.htm then replace `Job[1]` with `getmode(Job)`.

Comment: @Homard this works for your follow-up question:```setDT(df1)[order(Year), FirstJob:=names(sort(table(Job), decreasing = T)[1]), .(Name)][]``` However, it won't give you the first job if there's no most common job (Alicia's case here).

Answer (score 2):

We can group by  'Name' and extract the `first` 'Job' to create the new column 'FirstJob'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Name) %>%
   mutate(FirstJob = first(Job))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   Name [2]
#  Name    Year Job       FirstJob 
#  <chr>  <int> <chr>     <chr>    
#1 Alicia  1990 Butcher   Butcher  
#2 Alicia  1991 Baker     Butcher  
#3 George  1989 Scientist Scientist
#4 George  1990 Banker    Scientist
#5 George  1991 Banker    Scientist
```

---

If the 'Year' is not ordered

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(Name) %>%
   mutate(FirstJob = Job[which.min(Year)])
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("Alicia", "Alicia", "George", "George", 
"George"), Year = c(1990L, 1991L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L), Job = c("Butcher", 
"Baker", "Scientist", "Banker", "Banker")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```